# Cross-country skiing world records

Tags: records, skiing, cross-country-skiing

Are there any current world records for cross-country skiing? I am mainly interrested in distances like 10 or 15 kilometers, both men and women included. Neither Google nor Wikipedia are able to answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timing in cross country skiing has no purpose but to classify the runners. There are no international records, and even so they will be untrustable because of different conditions of snow and the fact that CC does not have a unique track like, for example, a 100 metre sprint does.

Comment: Just a comment: marathons don't have a unique track, but the IAAF now records [marathon world records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_world_record_progression). I accept that cross-country skiing courses vary more than a marathon course, but this isn't an absolute prohibition.

Comment: But even in marathon is talk of fast and less fast marathon courses (see [http://www.runnersworld.com/races/the-worlds-fastest-marathons-and-marathoners]. So you would never try to run wolrd record on a slow course.